# Center align a div underneath a row of divs using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

This is how it looks now.

[image]

I want the `välj` div to be centered below the other ones.

I am using flexbox.

What I have done now is to wrap all the divs in a container, and then add:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

to the container

the row of divs also have a container around it. With the value:

```
display: flex;   
flex-flow: row;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The last "button" div (`välj`), has the value `align-self: center;`.

Am I missing something, or should now it be centered by now?

Comment: Can you please post the full code or any fiddle link?

Comment: Add your html and proper css.

Comment: `align-self: center` doesn't work in the way you expect. Add your html and I'll post an answer showing how-to.

Comment: display: flex;  is used for container not the children.

Comment: If everything is clear and nothing missing, it would be great if you could accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Gerard's answer does work. It did not for me, on my site. Since I have a bunch of inherited css from code writen years ago. This, however, did work.

```css
.sub-slider {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; 
    flex-flow: column;
}
.slider {
  display: flex;   
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sub-slider-btn-wrp { 
  align-self: center;
}
.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-slider">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-slider-btn-wrp">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `align-*` properties in Flexbox (`align-items/content/self`) defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items along the cross-axis of their container.

So in your case, where the *container* has *row* direction, the `align-self: center` will center the button vertically, though if its parent doesn't have a height higher than the flex item, one won't visually see it.

Based on you say there is one *row div* around the price items and one around the button, you have two main options to center the button:

1. Change the *container* to *column* direction and the `align-self: center` will center the button horizontally.
2. Replace `align-self: center` with `margin: auto`

Comment: In my answer, I changed the container to display columns, the "rows" to display rows and then centered the button with `align-self: center`.

Comment: @vonhact Yes, I saw that. Since the _why_ is more important than just a code sample, I posted my answer to explain why your initial solution didn't work and which available options there are.

Answer (score 0):

The below works with a flexbox for the row only.

```css
.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: thin solid red;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```